# Linux kernel manual build: resulting binary is 10 times larger than precompiled binaries

Tags: linux, compiling, linux-kernel

I'm using Linux Mint 13 MATE 32bit, I'm trying to build the kernel (primarily for experience and for fun).

For now, I like to build it with the same configuration as precompiled kernel, so firstly I've installed precompiled kernel 3.16.0-031600rc6 from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline), booted to it successfully.

Then I've downloaded 3.16.rc6 kernel from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/), unpacked it, configured it to use config from existing precompiled kernel:

```
$ make oldconfig
```

It didn't ask me anything, so, precompiled kernel contains all necessary information. Then I've built it (it took about 6 hours) :

```
$ make
```

And then installed:

```
$ sudo make modules_install install
```

Then I've booted into my manually-compiled kernel, and it works, boot process is somewhat slower though. But then I've found out that all the binaries (`/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-rc6` and all the `*.ko` modules in `/lib/modules/3.16.0-rc6/kernel` are about 10 times larger than precompiled versions! Say, `initrd.img-3.16.0-rc6` is `160 658 665` bytes, but precompiled `initrd.img-3.16.0-031600rc6-generic` is `16 819 611` bytes. Each `*.ko` module is similarly larger.

Why is this? I haven't specified any special options for build (I typed exactly the same commands as I mentioned above). How to build it "correctly"?

Comment: What about the compiler options? Are they the same?

Comment: (Tip: if you have more than 1 core/thread, use `make -jX` in the second step, with X the number of parallel processes make can use - start with #cores.)

Comment: @FaheemMitha, as far as I understand, all the compiler options are specified in `Makefile`, of course I haven't changed it in any way, and I haven't provided any special options: just `make oldconfig` and `make`. So, compiler options should be the same, right?

Comment: @Mat, thanks for the tip, but it's my old laptop for experiments, just one core there.

Comment: I'd suggest checking for and removing/redefining any options for debug symbols.

Comment: This is a good question -- while the actual kernel binary is about the same size, the same simple core modules (e.g. crypto implementations) are 5-10 times the size on disk when compiled from source than they are in my distro (fedora) package.  That's probably pretty noticeably if you use an external initrd, since it is mostly modules.  It's not @Hannu because of debugging symbols AFAICT; `file` reports them both as "not stripped".

Comment: `"not stripped"` - i.e. they contain "unstripped debug symbols" -> `$ ld --help | grep -i strip`

Comment: @Hannu But they are *both* like that, so that's not the issue; don't bother stripping them. What's interesting is I build most things in (i.e., I don't need any external initrd), but again, the actual kernel is only about 10% bigger.  It's the `.ko`s specifically.

Comment: =) considering the facts pointed out by Bruce in his answer, the kernel may well have the symbols too - within the compressed image.

Comment: I'm sure it does, but those things aren't normally loaded and don't make any difference at runtime, so stripping them out is pointless.  Dunno what all the extra bulk in the modules is though.

Comment: Howto: http://serverfault.com/a/251139

Comment: ^^ Again, that's obviously *not* the issue here.

Comment: Right -:-)  "not stripped" ^-- above.  I give up.

Comment: @Hannu I'm wrong!  It was debugging symbols (added an answer).

Comment: That is a big 'LOL' :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite what `file` says, it turns out to be debugging symbols after all.  [A thread about this on the LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/6/6/222) led me to try:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install
```

And low and behold, a comparison from within the `/lib/modules/x.x.x` directory; before:

```
> ls -hs kernel/crypto/anubis.ko 
112K kernel/crypto/anubis.ko
```

And after:

```
> ls -hs kernel/crypto/anubis.ko 
16K kernel/crypto/anubis.ko
```

More over, the total size of the directory (using the same `.config`) as reported by `du -h` went from 185 MB to 13 MB.

Keep in mind that beyond the use of disk space, this is not as significant as it may appear.   Debugging symbols are not loaded during normal runtime, so the actual size of each module in memory is probably identical regardless of the size of the `.ko` file.  I think the only significant difference it will make is in the size of the `initramfs` file, and the only difference it will make there is in the time needed to uncompress the fs.  I.e., if you use an *uncompressed* initramfs, it won't matter.

`strip --strip-all` also works, and `file` reports them correctly as `stripped` either way.  Why it says `not stripped` for the distro ones remains a mystery.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's quite strange that `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP` isn't set by default. My resulting `initrd.img-3.16.0-rc6` now takes 16 MB. Previously (with 160-MB `initrd`) when GRUB is finished, there was just black screen for about 7 seconds (unpacking, it seems), and only after it I see kernel messages. Now, with 16-MB `initrd`, kernel messages are echoed immediately after GRUB is finished. So, it is rather significant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After your `make oldconfig`, do a `make vmlinuz`. I think you'll find that the pre-compiled kernel is a "executable bzImage", which means it's compressed on-disk. If you watch boot messages closely, you'll see it uncompressing the kernel very early on in the process.

Comment: Thanks I'll try soon, but does this affect all the modules (`*.ko`) too?

Comment: I don't know about modules. That was one question I had before I recommeded `make vmlinuz`.