# How do compile Linux Driver for Netis WF2190 Wifi dongle for FriendlyARM mini210s?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, arm, cross-compilation

### GOAL

I want to install the Netis WF2190 wifi dongle linux driver onto my FriendlyARM mini210s.

### Environment

- [FriendlyARM mini210s S5PV210 ARM Cortex-A8 Board](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210s)
- ... running Linux 3.0.8-FriendlyARM
- [Netis WF2190](http://www.netis-systems.com/en/products/Dualband-Series/904.html)
- CROSS compiling with `arm/4.3.2/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`

I understand that I need to CROSS COMPILE the [Netis WF2190 Linux driver](http://www.netis-systems.com/Files/others/WF2190/netis%20WF2190%20Driver%20for%20Linux.rar)

### I am Using a virtual machine for cross-compilation (vagrant box)

```
$ uname -a
Linux vagrant 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have downloaded and copied my driver into my VM

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902$
```

In the drivers `Makefile`, I added these

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n
CONFIG_PLATFORM_FRIENDLYARM_MINI210S = y     <====
```

and then

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLATFORM_FRIENDLYARM_MINI210S), y)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN
ARCH := arm
CROSS_COMPILE := /home/vagrant/friendlyarm/tools/usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
KVER  := 3.0.8
KSRC := /home/vagrant/friendlyarm/linux-3.0.8/kernel
endif
```

and then tried to compile, but I get this error,

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902$ make
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/vagrant/robot-os/friendlyarm/tools/usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi- -C /home/vagrant/robot-os/friendlyarm/linux-3.0.8/kernel  M=/home/vagrant/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/robot-os/friendlyarm/linux-3.0.8/kernel'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/robot-os/friendlyarm/linux-3.0.8/kernel'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Worth noting that I am NOT a specialist, I am trying to learn what to do to reach my objective.

At this stage, I just don't understand what the message is telling me, and how I could fix it.

Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: If you are following some instructions or tutorial from somewhere, you should post a link to that.  Your methodology here appears kind of unorthodox to me.

Comment: yes most likely totally unorthodox, I have no clue how to do it. This what I have tried. People shout if you ask for help without trying hard before. This is me trying hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel source path was wrong, I corrected it to:

```
KSRC := /home/vagrant/friendlyarm/linux-3.0.8/
```

and it compiled

Answer (score 0):

> In the drivers Makefile, I added these

That's not the way to go about this.  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115621/25985) -- you can probably skip to step #3.

> then tried to compile, but I get this error

From your cut and paste, it looks like you ran `make` before `make modules` and nothing happened.  That's no good.  `make` should actually build the kernel, which may or may not be necessary to make a module (not sure if it *should be*, but sometimes it seems to be).  That takes at least a few minutes and should produce lots of output.  If that didn't happen, something is very wrong.

I've cross built kernels using gcc via crosstool-ng and have to set `TARGET`; you don't appear to have done that (but the distro cross-compiler may be different).  However, setting this stuff by tinkering with the kernel makefile is probably a mistake.  Just do it in the environment:

```
export TARGET=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=/foo/bar/etc
```

Put that in a text file and just source it before you run make (`source my_environment.sh`).

Comment: Note that I modified the Netis driver Makefile, not the kernel MAkefile. I have built the kernel successfully before that. I am trying to cross compile the Netis driver, not the kernel. (Just making sure you got that)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Can't look in the `.rar` right now either (why would they distribute a linux driver that way?? Not very promising...).  [This page](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Netis_WF2190) implies a [realtek 8812au driver](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) might work, you could have a look at that.  Unfortunately I don't do out-of-tree drivers much so I'm not much help with this.

Comment: No worries. I have just learned more today, this last input is already of great help.